# Как в NavigationView добавить иконку снизу?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Как в NavigationView добавить иконку снизу?
То бишь, чтобы она находилась в самом низу гамбургера.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` является `ViewGroup`, так что вы можете просто добавить картинку в разметку, как и в любой другой контейнер:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```